# Code optimization - looping through/searching for email from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a macro which loops through items in my Inbox and returns these send by ReportProvider (saves details in Table1). At this point the macro works well but in my opinion it's slow - it takes approx 2 minutes to loop through 6000 emails.

Is there a way to do it faster?

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getOutlookData()

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As Object
Dim oFolder, oSubFolder  As Outlook.Folder
Dim oSubject, oSender, oTime, oSubFolderID As String
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim i, j, k, counter As Integer

Set oApp = New Outlook.Application

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("Table1").AutoFilter
If Range("Table1").Rows.Count > 1 Then Range("Table1").Rows.Delete ' clear the table

i = 1
'========================= Get Number of Emails =========================
counter = 0
For Each oFolder In Outlook.Session.Folders
    If oFolder.Name = "wujaszkun@company-where-i-work.com" Then
        For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.Folders
            If oSubFolder.Name = "Inbox" Then
                oSubFolderID = oSubFolder.EntryID
                counter = counter + oSubFolder.Items.Count
            End If
        Next oSubFolder
    End If
Next oFolder
'========================= /Get Number of Emails =========================


'========================= Get Emails sent by provider =========================
Set oSubFolder = Outlook.Session.GetFolderFromID(oSubFolderID)
For Each oMail In oSubFolder.Items

    statusView.Show ' show status dialog
    Call Status(oMail.Parent.Parent.Name & "/" & oMail.Parent.Name, oMail.Subject, "Checked " & k & "/" & counter) 'update status dialog

    k = k + 1
    If oMail.Class = 43 Then

        If oMail.SenderName = "ReportRrovider" Then
        With Range("Table1")
            statusView.Label4 = "Found " & j ' update status dialog
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = oMail.Parent.Parent.Name & "/" & oMail.Parent.Name
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = oMail.SenderName
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = oMail.Subject
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = CDate(oMail.SentOn)
            If oMail.attachments.Count > 0 Then .Cells(i, 5).Value = oMail.attachments.Item(1).Size
            If oMail.attachments.Count > 0 Then .Cells(i, 6).Value = oMail.attachments(1).DisplayName
            .Cells(i, 7).Value = oMail.EntryID
            .Cells(i, 8).Value = oSubFolder.EntryID
            .Cells(i, 9).Value = CDate(oMail.ReceivedTime)
            .Cells(i, 10).Formula = "=VLOOKUP([@Attachment],MappingTable[#All],2,0)"
            .Cells(i, 10).Copy
            .Cells(i, 10).PasteSpecial xlValues
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
        End With
        End If
    End If
Next oMail

Unload statusView ' hide status dialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Call downloadAttachments

End Sub

Sub status(Optional ByVal caption1 As String, Optional ByVal caption2 As String, Optional ByVal caption3 As String, Optional ByVal caption4 As String)


            If caption1 <> "" Then statusView.label1.Caption = caption1
            If caption2 <> "" Then statusView.label2.Caption = caption2
            If caption3 <> "" Then statusView.label3.Caption = caption3
            If caption4 <> "" Then statusView.Label4.Caption = caption4
End Sub
```

I'll appreciate if you could post a method/trick with explanation on how it works or why is it better solution rather than just code-answer. It's important for me to learn these things :)

Best Regards

Wujaszkun

Comment: Perhaps create an inbox rule that moves the emails from that sender to their own folder when they arrive, then run the macro on that folder only.

Comment: You're putting entries into cells as individual transactions which would likely be slowing this down massively. A better approach would be to put the entire dataset into an array as you iterate through and then paste that array into the worksheet.

Comment: I agree with @Zerk - reading and writing every time from the spreadsheet takes time.

Comment: Thank for all the replies!

There are just around 100 of emails to be saved in the table each time so it's not a large volume, but i will definitely try out saving it trough array,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, ever loop through all items in a folder. Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`. The query you want is `"[SenderName] = 'ReportRrovider'"`.

Also, there is absolutely no reason to calculate `oMail.Parent.Parent.Name & "/" & oMail.Parent.Name` on each step of the loop: the value will be the same for all items in a given folder. calculate it before entering the loop

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot especially the `Items.Restrict`. It shortened the code execution time from approx 90 seconds to 7-8 seconds and the code itself is more transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the update ideas:

```
Dim oSubject as string, oSender as string , oTime as string, oSubFolderID As String
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim i as long, j as long, k as long, counter As long
```

This way you declare them explicitly to the given type, otherwise they are variant, and this is expensive. Furthermore, do not use Integer in VBA, it is smaller and slower than long.

Comment: @ShaiRado how is it "almost true"? from the exact link you post: "in fact, Long variables might be slightly faster because VBA does not have to convert them.". Vityata is correct.

Comment: @ShaiRado why do you assume that the OP is using an old machine and old office?

Comment: @ShaiRado Vityata was recommending good practice, both in terms of explicitly typing variables as well as choosing appropriate types. His advice was solid.

Comment: @Vityata nevermind, even though i disagree, I will remove my comments, since this back and fourth is not a part of this post. B.T.W , I guess smeone else thought like me (since I did not downvote your answer )

Comment: I'm using Office 2010 so i think this could save me some seconds.